# Validation message in the controller with spring MVC, for an onetomany list

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have already validated many-to-one in my controller so I will not leave a tour for the same unit. But I need to do the reverse for onetomany and I can not traverse my list before saving and validating by returning the message.

I'll explain the functional code:
The business rule says that it can not contain the same tour registered in the unit:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="horario_aula")
public class HorarioAula implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "horario_aula_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "horario_aula_id_seq", sequenceName = "horario_aula_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@JsonIgnore
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "turno_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Turno turno;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "unidade_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Unidade unidade;

@Valid
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "horarioAula", orphanRemoval=true)
private List<Horario> horarios;

setting eng getting.....
```

This entity contains an onetomany relation List <>

```
@Entity
@Table(name="horario")
public class Horario implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "horario_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "horario_id_seq", sequenceName = "horario_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "horario_aula_id", referencedColumnName ="id")
private HorarioAula horarioAula;


@NotNull
@Column(name = "duracao")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern ="HH:mm")
private Date duracao;


@NotNull
@Column(name ="hora_inicial")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HH:mm")
private Date horaInicial;

@NotNull
@Column(name ="hora_final")
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIME )
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HH:mm")
private Date horaFinal;

setting eng getting.....
```

The business rule says that it can not contain the same tour registered in the unit.

**MY CONTROLLER: SALVE...**

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('PERM_HORARIO_AULA_CADASTRAR', 
'PERM_HORARIO_AULA_ALTERAR')")
@RequestMapping(value="/novo",params = ("btnSave"),method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String salvarHorarioAula(@Validated HorarioAula horarioAula, Errors errors, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
   ****if(horarioAula.getTurno() != null) {
    ****    if (horarioAulaService.validarTurnoExistente(horarioAula.getUnidade().getId(), horarioAula.getTurno().getId())) {
            errors.rejectValue("turno", "mensagem.validacao.turno.existente");
        }
    }

    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("======================"+ errors.getAllErrors());
        return "/horario-aula/formulario";
    }

    try {
        if(horarioAula.getId() == 0) mensagem = mensagemSucesso(MensagemEnum.MENSAGEM_SUCESSO_CADASTRAR.getMensagem());
        else mensagem = mensagemSucesso(MensagemEnum.MENSAGEM_SUCESSO_ALTERAR.getMensagem());
        horarioAulaService.salvar(horarioAula);
    } catch (CustomException e) {
        mensagem = mensagemErro(e.getMessage());
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", mensagem);
        return "redirect:/horario-aula/novo";
    }

    attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", mensagem);
    return "redirect:/horario-aula";
}
```

horarioAulaService calls my method of service validarTurnoExistente that does the validation, this n does not go into detail because I used @Query in the repository ..

errors.rejectValue Returns the message for the tour "turno"

These are the results:

[image]

[image]

After this long explanation, I will need to apply this method to a dynamic list

Object course"curso" has a cursoTurno list that contains Number of places and Tour
Tour can not be registered the same.

I must do the list verifying before saving so I can not create a new list.

**MY CONTROLLER**:

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('PERM_CURSO_CADASTRAR', 'PERM_CURSO_ALTERAR')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/novo", params = {"btnSave"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String salvarCurso(@Validated Curso curso, Errors errors,
                      ****    List<CursoTurno> listaCursoTurno ,Errors errorsCursoTurno,
                          RedirectAttributes attributes) {

******    for (CursoTurno cursoTurno: listaCursoTurno) {
        System.out.println("----------------============================");
        System.out.println(cursoTurno.getTurno());
******    }

    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
       // System.out.println(errors.getAllErrors() );
        return "/curso/formulario";
    }
        try {
            if (curso.getId() == 0)
                mensagem = mensagemSucesso(MensagemEnum.MENSAGEM_SUCESSO_CADASTRAR.getMensagem());
            else mensagem = mensagemSucesso(MensagemEnum.MENSAGEM_SUCESSO_ALTERAR.getMensagem());
            cursoService.salvar(curso);

        } catch (CustomException e) {
            //  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            mensagem = mensagemErro(e.getMessage());
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", mensagem);
            return "redirect:/curso/novo";
        }

        attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", mensagem);
        return "redirect:/curso";
    }
```

I did this to try to print the tour ve if it is passing the object, without the foreach funicona the list this courseTurno cursoturno, but I need the List

List  contains Number of places and Tour.

Comment: Images https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYT91.png [3]       http://imgur.com/a/tujks and [4]

Comment: please add tags jpa or hibernate , to get attention towards this question

Comment: Can i use json request to automatically validate? Before you click save